# Convert float seconds to milliseconds using regex with Notepad++

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++, milliseconds, seconds

I want to convert all seconds contained in the XML tag to milliseconds using regex with Notepad++.

Before converting:

```
<keepTime>3</keepTime>
<keepTime>4.5</keepTime>
<keepTime>0.7</keepTime>
<keepTime>1.85</keepTime>
```

The results I want after converting:

```
<keepTime>3000</keepTime>
<keepTime>4500</keepTime>
<keepTime>700</keepTime>
<keepTime>1850</keepTime>
```

Here is the regex I use: `<keepTime>([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+</keepTime>`

It matches all the values in `<keepTime>`. However, I have no idea what to replace into milliseconds.

If your answer was helpful, I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to search and replace in multiple files, or just a single one? I'd suggest using a PythonScript based solution, it would be easiest to implement. Regex will be unreadable.

Comment: Are there also values with a format like 0.0000007 or 9999.853456 ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I followed the solution below, it is quite simple and safe. But most of all, it gave me the correct result for the question asked.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, I'm using Notepad++ v7.8.6 and RE on it match those values. However, my file has no such small / large value.

Comment: That is a combination of several regexps that do not cover [all cases](https://regex101.com/r/0xrL9y/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It [matches all](https://regex101.com/r/EAxKhI/1) of the test strings you have given.

Comment: But does not handle them all.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I am using solution of AdrianHHH. However, one shortcoming with the answer is that it has not been resolved with values less than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I frequently use regular expressions (RE), I would be reluctant to use one complex RE for this job. The chances that it misses some of the tags, or wrongly converts others, seem too high and too risky. I would approach this sort of task using a series of simple REs that jointly give me confidence that I have done all the changes correctly.

Thus, with "Regular expression" and "Wrap around" selected:

Change `<keepTime>(\d+)</keepTime>` to `<done>${1}000</done>`

Change `<keepTime>(\d+)\.(\d)</keepTime>` to `<done>${1}${2}00</done>`

Change `<keepTime>(\d+)\.(\d\d)</keepTime>` to `<done>${1}${2}0</done>`

To remove all leading zeros but retain a single zero, use

Change `<done>0+([1-9]\d*)</done>` to `<done>${1}</done>`

For a variation on the above to remove some leading zeros but keep three digits, use:

Change `<done>0+(\d\d\d)</done>` to `<done>${1}</done>`

It is simple to modify it to keep two digits or four, etc.

Now do a search for any remaining occurrences of `</?keepTime>` and change them in the style above. Then when they are all changed, convert the "done"s  with:

Change `<done>(\d+)</done>` to `<keepTime>\1</keepTime>`.

Now do a final check that all of the "done"s have been done, searching for `</?done>`

Note that `done` should be replaced throughout by some tag that is not used in the original file. Note also that this is complex editing, so make a backup before doing the changes.

Comment: Your replacement seems inaccurate. I used as you write and the result I get is: `<done>{1}000</done>`.But I edited the replacement field to: `<keepTime>\1000</keepTime>` (remove curly braces and backslash) then the result I get is exactly as in the question. But anyway, your solution worked. Nothing went wrong (so you can feel secure about the RE you write).

Comment: @TầnQuảng My apologies, the `\{1}` etc  should have been `${1}` etc. The curly braces are needed because `\1000` or `$1000` etc can refer to the one-thousandth capture group, not capture group one followed by `000`. The answer has been updated.

Comment: One problem is that it doesn't remove leading zeros with numbers less than 1 (Example: 0.7 would become 0700 instead of 700; or 0.01 would become 0010 instead of 10). Do you have a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Doing numeric multiplication using regular expressions feels like attempting to drive a nail using a screwdriver, and I certainly wouldn't attempt it in a single replace() call, but if you're allowed a bit of conditional logic then it's not too difficult:

```
(a) if there's no ".", append "000"
(b) otherwise:
   (i) append "000"
   (ii) replace ".xxx" by "xxx."
   (iii) delete trailing zeroes
   (iv) delete trailing "."
```